# Mock a method call called by a class method

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I am writing unit tests for my application, I need to mock a call made by a class method, to a method in another module, but I can't work out how to set the mock path.

I have basically overridden the critical method of the logging class to email when `logger.critical()` is called. In my test I want to mock the call to `sendemail()` that is within the critical method.

In the test I am deleting "username" from the good set of config to test that missing a mandatory config value calls `logger.critical()` and exit. I also have to mock several other external boto3 calls, they are working fine.

app/tests/test_config.py

```
    @patch.dict(os.environ, {"AWS_REGION": region, "CW_MODE": mode})
    @patch('app.config.parse_config.get_from_ssm')
    @patch('app.config.parse_config.process_queue')
    @patch("app.config.parse_config.logger.critical.sendemail")
    def test_parse_args_no_mandatory(self, mock_sendmail, mock_process_queue, mock_get_from_ssm):
        mock_get_from_ssm.side_effect = ["x", "y"]
        tmp_config = copy.deepcopy(good_min_config)
        mock_sendmail.return_value = None
        del tmp_config["username"]
        mock_process_queue.return_value = tmp_config

        with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
            parse_config()

        self.assertEqual(SystemExit, pytest_wrapped_e.type)
        self.assertEqual("config option: username not supplied", pytest_wrapped_e.value.code)
```

app/utils/logging.py

```
class CwLogger(logging.Logger):

    def __init__(self, name, level=logging.NOTSET):
        super(CwLogger, self).__init__(name, level)

    def critical(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        caller = getframeinfo(stack()[1][0])
        send_msg = f"{caller.filename.split('/')[-1]} line {caller.lineno} {caller.function}() {msg}"

        sendemail(config.conf["email"], send_msg, error=True)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        super(CwLogger, self).critical(msg, stacklevel=2, *args, **kwargs)
        raise SystemExit(msg)


logging.setLoggerClass(CwLogger)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

app/config/parse_config.py

```
def parse_config():

    # Get our config from SQS
    config.conf = process_queue()

    # Make sure that any options with defaults are set correctly if not supplied, and mandatory options are present
    for k in base_config:
        if k not in config.conf and base_config[k]["mandatory"]:
            logger.critical(f"config option: {k} not supplied")
```

app/utils/sendemail.py

```
def sendemail(email, content, error=False):
    """
    Sends an email to the email specified in config with the provided content, will try to verify the email,
    if this fails 3 times then we give up.

    :param email: The email address to send to
    :param content: The content of the email to send
    :param error: Flag to signal to use the error template
    :return: None.
    """
    <code to send email that I want to mock>
```

Comment: you need to patch `app.utils.logging.sendemail`

Comment: wow, I swear I tried that along with many other combinations, but you are indeed correct, that fixed it. Thank you!